# Regex match all instances of character except when followed by a digit or is by itself

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Trying to match every instance of `@` except if followed by a `digit` or is by itself in `js`.

`@(?!\d)` finds all that are followed by `digit`

`1@ @1 1 j@  @j @j1 1j@ j1 1j @@1     @` <-- don't want to match by itself

---

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrZEVQ/7/)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `@(?!\d)` matches `@`s that are NOT followed with a digit

Comment: maybe this `@(?!\d|@)` ?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to combine @(?!\d) rule with additional rule to also not match any instances of @ by itself

Comment: Are you replacing the matches? What with? What is the expected result?

Comment: replacing match with nothing -- removing all instances for example @username = username but 100 @ $50 is unchanged

Comment: Try `s.replace(/((?:^|\s)@)(?!\S)|@(?!\d)/g, '$1')`, see https://regex101.com/r/GEz9kU/1

Comment: Great, I posted [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53801361/3832970)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to remove any `@` that are not enclosed with whitespace and that are not followed with a digit. The easiest approach is to match and capture the `@` enclosed with whitespaces and match all other `@` not followed with a digit, and replace with the Group 1 placeholder, `$1`:

```
s.replace(/((?:^|\s)@)(?!\S)|@(?!\d)/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEz9kU/1/)

**Details**

- `((?:^|\s)@)(?!\S)` -  Group 1: start of string or a whitespace (`(?:^|\s)`) and then `@`, that is not followed with a non-whitespace char (`(?!\S)`, equal to `(?=\s|$)`, whitespace or end of string)
- `|` - or
- `@(?!\d)` - a `@` not followed with a digit (`(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a digit)